# Javascript - Change colour of div based on current colour

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the background colour of a div based on it's current colour, via the click of a button.

For example, if the colour is cyan (#00ffff - it should change to yellow ('ffff00).

If the colour is yellow - it should change to magenta (#ff00ff).

If the colour is magenta - it should revert back to cyan.

I have managed to change the color to yellow from cyan, however I am not sure exactly how to write my if statement (assuming an if statement is the best way?) to change the colours based on the current colour.

```js
 function ColorFunction() {
   if (light.getItem("backgroundColor") == '#00ffff') {
     document.getElementById("light").style.backgroundColor = "#ffff00";
   }
   else
     if (light.getItem("backgroundColor") == '#ffff00') {
       document.getElementById("light").style.backgroundColor = "#ff00ff";
     }
   else
     if (light.getItem("backgroundColor") == '#ff00ff') {
       document.getElementById("light").style.backgroundColor = "00ffff";
     }
 }
```

```css
.main {
  width:250px;
  color: #202020;
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
}

.light {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #00ffff
}

#burn {
  width: 150px;
  font-style: italic;
}

#button {
  font-style: bold;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Disco Inferno</h1>
    <div class="light" id="light">
      div
    </div>

    <button onClick="ColorFunction()">Burn!</button>
```

Comment: this isnt [codereview.se] its StackOverflow ;)

Comment: console.log() will show you why it fails. Use classes.

Comment: @Jamiec So...that would be the first mistake.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic; it may (or may not) be appropriate to http://codereview.stackexchange.com but be sure to check their help first.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is not a code review question... And no way is it a fit for there. Code review needs working code, this is far from working.

Comment: Ive made this a code snippet, so at least someone can copy it to an answer - but it does not work at present!

Comment: @epascarello: Just working off the OP's own opening. I did say *"...but be sure to check their help first...."* :-) (Since I don't hang out in coderview.)

Comment: That snippet will not work, `light` var is undefined

Comment: getItem <-- what is that? That is not a DOM method.

Comment: OK!! sorry, my bad :(

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude well it is defined in a way. `console.log(light)` will show it as a DOM element.

Comment: However, OP said that the change to yellow works, so the problem is not in `light` var, is on the conditions

Comment: @epascarello not in the snippet.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I bet you the internet that it is defined in Chrome.

Comment: Your chrome is crazy. It's clearly undefined on the snippet. Where do you see `light` defined on the op's code?

Comment: I trust in you, but how browser set a DOM element to an undefined variable? Just because the name?

Comment: And what is `getItem()` function? OP said that yellow change works. I'm very very confused

Comment: Because it does. If the browser does not find a variable with it, it looks at the DOM for the id.

Comment: First notice of that behaviour since 15 years ago that I am develop with Javascript... I'm not sure that's a good praxis.

Comment: 15 years? IE has done it since the beginning of time.

Comment: Yeah, 15 years ago I started to test this language, I was HTML and FrontPage developer (and C++). But for my own health, I will never do that. I will define all variables in my code. I don't know what advantage has the refference to DOM element in an undefined variable.

Comment: OK - before I read any furthur I just want to clarify an error I made in the OP. I have got it to change to yellow, but then I added the if statement (so now it does not work).

As for the 'getItem' statement...It was a guess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, lets start at the beginning here.

You have an element with the id `light` but that does not automatically become a variable you can use in javascript. Its easy enough to make it one:

```
var light = document.getElementById("light");
```

Then, i'm not even sure where you get `getItem` from - perhaps it was a guess - but its not a valid method on an [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)

You could do this with `light.style.backgroundColor` - see the snippet below.

```js
var colors = ["rgb(0, 255, 255)","rgb(255, 255, 0)","rgb(255, 0, 255)"];

function ColorFunction() { 
   var light = document.getElementById("light");
   var curr = light.style.backgroundColor;
   var next = colors.indexOf(curr)+1;
   light.style.backgroundColor = colors[next%colors.length];
 }
```

```html
<h1>Disco Inferno</h1>
<div class="light" id="light" style="background-color:#00FFFF">
    Burn, baby burn!
</div>

    <button onClick="ColorFunction()">Burn!</button>
```

Comment: *"You have an element with the id light but that does not automatically become a variable you can use in javascript."* Actually, it does. Elements with `id`s get [*automatic globals* created for them](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sshhhhh now. Lets not make people believe its a good idea to *use* them.

Comment: **:-)** I've given up on that, since it actually got added to the spec.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an object for shifting the colors, after assigning directly a color to the div.

```js
function ColorFunction() {
    var colors = {
            'rgb(0, 255, 255)': 'rgb(255, 255, 0)',
            'rgb(255, 255, 0)': 'rgb(255, 0, 255)',
            'rgb(255, 0, 255)': 'rgb(0, 255, 255)'
        },
        element = document.getElementById("light");
    element.style.backgroundColor = colors[element.style.backgroundColor];
}
```

```css
.main { width:250px; color: #202020; background-color: #d0d0d0; }
.light { width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: #00ffff; }
#burn { width: 150px; font-style: italic; }
#button { font-style: bold; width: 150px; }
```

```html
<div class="light" id="light" style="background-color: #00ffff;"></div>
<button onClick="ColorFunction()">Burn!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no getItem() that is some made up method. Look at the console and you will see that it is an error. To read background color you should be using style.

```
var color = elementReference.style.backgroundColor
```

Now you are relying on a bad feature of JavaScript where you define a variable that matches an id of an element and it is magically a reference to that element.You should not do that. You should define the variable yourself.

```
var elementReference = document.getElementById("light");
```

Now the kicker, browsers returning different things when you read color values. SOme hex, some rgb. So checking for color is a bad thing to do. What to do? Use CSS classes.

```js
function ColorFunction(){
   var elem = document.getElementById("light");
   if(elem.classList.contains("red")) {
     elem.classList.remove("red");
     elem.classList.add("blue");
   } else if(elem.classList.contains("blue")) {
     elem.classList.remove("blue");
     elem.classList.add("green");
   } else {
     elem.classList.remove("green");
     elem.classList.add("red");     
   }
}
```

```css
.red { background-color: red;}
.blue {background-color: blue;}
.green {background-color: green;}
```

```html
<h1>Disco Inferno</h1>
<div class="light red" id="light">
  div
</div>

<button onClick="ColorFunction()">Burn!</button>
```

Now there are other ways to do the if check with add/remove, but that is the basic idea.